# Restricting to affine charts

Tags: analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

this is a fairly basic question that I'm struggling with. I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Let $C$ be an affine or projective plane curve over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $p$ be a smooth point of $C$.
> Show that $p$ has an open neighbourhood in $C$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

In the affine case, this seems to be a direct application of the inverse function theorem, which I state here:

> $Q$ is a non-constant polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x, y],$ and let $D$ be the affine plane curve defined by $Q=0 .$ Let $(a, b)$ be a point in $D$ such that $\partial_{y} Q(a, b) \neq 0 .$ Then there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $(a, b)$ in $D$ such that the projection
> $$
> \psi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C},(x, y) \mapsto x
> $$
> is a homeomorphism onto an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb{C},$ and such that the composition of $\psi^{-1}: V \rightarrow U$ with the projection $\mathbb{C}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{C},(x, y) \mapsto y$ is holomorphic.

So from the above set $V$, I can find an open disk around point $p$ identified to be in $V$ (i.e. $\psi(p)$), and this is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

But in the case of the projective plane curve, the only explanation that I'm given is that "we can intersect $C$ with an affine chart containing $p$ to reduce to the affine case". I can't justify this line. My attempt would be something like:

> $V$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$ $\iff$ $\exists$ $W \subset \mathbb{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$ such that $W \cap C = V$, and $W \cap U_i$ is open in $U_i$ for $i = 0,1,2$ $\iff$... something appropriate to justify the above step.

Could anyone help with this? Thanks. $U_i$ is defined as in the conventional sense, such that $U_i$ form an open cover of $\mathbb{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the affine charts $U_i$ cover $\mathbb{P}^2$, there is some $i$ such that $p \in U_i$. Let $f : \mathbb{C}^2 \to U_i$ be the canonical homeomorphism. Now "pull back" $C$ to a plane curve $C' \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ (what polynomial should this be given by?). Then $C'$ is an affine plane curve such that $f(C') = U_i \cap C$.

We have $f^{-1}(p) \in C'$, and we can check that $f^{-1}(p)$ is a smooth point of $C'$. Thus, there is an open neighborhood $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ of $f^{-1}(p)$ such that $V \cap C' \cong \mathbb{C}$. Finally, $f(V) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ such that $$f(V) \cap C = f(V \cap C') \cong V \cap C' \cong \mathbb{C},$$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate a bit on why "$f(V) \cap C = f(V \cap C')$"?

Comment: Sure -- $f$ is injective, so $f(V \cap C') = f(V) \cap f(C') = f(V) \cap C \cap U_i = f(V) \cap C$